# Adding reverse polarity protection to battery discharge circuit

Tags: voltage, transistors, reverse-polarity

I'll open with a caveat - I have zero training in the field but I do like tinkering. I'll try to make my question as specific as possible but do forgive if info is missing at this stage!

First of all, I've already built this little circuit
[image: Battery discharge circuit]

So far so good. Now, what this is missing is reverse polarity protection. The moment you reverse the polarity the TL431 blows.

I've read up on a couple of common methods: using a diode and using a PNP transistor.

I've encountered issues with both so I'd like some help on making either of these work or perhaps on an entirely different solution.

Before we dive in, a bit more detail:
- The bulb at the end of the circuit is 50W
- The input voltage is 12v (but all this needs to also work at 15v))
- The circuit runs the bulb until the Vin reaches 11.6v, at which point it switches off

So... diode:
- I played around with where I could use a diode here. The diodes I have are too weak to withstand being between the 12v+ and the rest of the circuit (did try it... reversing the polarity destroyed the diode)
- I then tried a few locations around the TL431 and I found that if placed just before the TL431's anode it does the job. It protects the TL from reverse current. However, the issue here is that the circuit doesn't switch off at 11.6v any more. I guess I can play with the 12k resistor to compensate but I'm afraid that different diodes may produce a different voltage drop and hence make the circuit unreliable (I'm making more than one of these)

PNP:
- Even less success with this one. I tried it on the TL431's anode and nothing worked, tried it in reference (and even... cathode) and the TL blew.
- I tried a few values for the bias resistor (3k, 6k, 10k, 15k) - no difference
- Here's the specific one I'm using http://grobotronics.com/images/datasheets/DS013184.PDF

So, as you can tell an absolute amateur so any and all help very welcome!

Comment: A simple 1N4001 placed in series with the battery should do the job. It has a reverse polarity of 50V. Source: http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ds28002.pdf

Comment: 1N4001 is too small for 1.8A. Use a 1N540x.

Comment: Thanks Spehro! The 1N540x seems to be absolutely fine for voltage but output current is 3A. I think this won't be enough as we need around 4.5A for this

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried power diodes? There most certainly exists diodes that can withstand 15 V. Here's a [quick search](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv916=2&pv916=22&pv916=31&pv916=23&pv916=32&pv916=17&pv916=24&pv916=21&pv916=25&pv916=18&pv916=11&pv916=28&pv916=27&pv916=111&pv916=19&pv916=29&pv916=7&pv916=69&pv916=15&pv916=33&pv916=6&pv916=130&pv916=58&pv916=123&pv916=16&pv916=53&pv916=14&pv916=5&pv916=42&pv916=36&pv916=40&pv916=35&pv916=41&pv916=43&pv916=44&pv916=60&pv916=68&pv916=62&pv916=61&pv916=46&pv916=63&pv916=67&pv916=120&pv916=139&pv916=140&pv916=65&FV=fff40015%2Cfff8007f&k=power%20diode&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=1&rohs=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) for single diodes that can withstand more than 15 V. The position would be in series right after the battery + terminal

A diode would also have been my first go to method for prevent reverse polarity. This TI [application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva139/slva139.pdf) mentions another strategy of using MOSFET switches to prevent reverse flow.

Lastly, if neither of these electrical methods work out, is there some specific shape of battery that you are using, such that you could prevent the reverse polarity in a mechanical fashion? That's one more option.

Comment: Also a note for the OP: if you do use a diode, you'll need to adjust your cut-off voltage. a silicon diode drops about 0.7 volts in the forward direction so your current circuit will cut off at 12.3 volts.

Comment: Hi Mike - thanks for the answer! You're right - many diodes are cool with 15v. My issue however seems to be the amps draw. All diodes I found were OK with milliamps, or maybe an amp. The circuit draws 4.5 amps.

Comment: For example, I tried this one and while it worked fine in normal polarity, when reversing it it just let the current through after a certain amperage http://grobotronics.com/images/datasheets/datasheet-1N4148.113.pdf